# How do I add this unallocated space to my Ubuntu partition using GParted?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Here is how my GParted interface looks like:

[image: gparted]

I want to add the unallocated space to my Ubuntu partition. However, when I try to resize/move I am not allowed to do so:

[image: attempt]

Comment: In addition to answer below, you have two choices, move partition left & expand right. Note that partitioning editing can be dangerous, so good backups always required. You could also create another partition and use it as /home. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: status please...

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 1):

GParted doesn't allow you to modify partitions when they are active. Boot from a LiveUSB and launch GParted from there, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Do the following...**

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** sda5 partition all the way left
- **resize** the right side of sda5 all the way right
- click the Apply icon